# angular 14 template driven Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'control')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-template, angular-template-form

I need to refer my form to do some think. This my hmtl code is:

```
   <form #formField="ngForm">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="section-border">
```

I need to take the  refer to form so I do this in my ts:

```
  @ViewChild('formField', { static: true }) flux: NgForm; 

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log("first");
    console.log(this.flux) //here is undefined
```

The problem is when I need to take the form, it is undefined.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The ngOnInit lifecycle hook is called before the view children are initialized.
Try to use **ngAfterViewInit** (from interface AfterViewInit in @angular/core) instead:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
   console.log('flux', this.flux);
}
```

More info on lifecycle hooks order: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks